# Why CPU time is not constant for the same input?

Tags: c++, time, cpu

I am measuring the CPU time of an algorithm:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
loop 10000 times
    <My algorithms here>
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
duration = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec); // in nanoseconds
```

As I understand, CPU time does not depend on on I/O, cache, ..., but only the instructions:

> CPU time (or process time) is the amount of time for which a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions of a computer program or operating system, as opposed to, for example, waiting for input/output (I/O) operations or entering low-power (idle) mode. (Wikipedia)

For different runs, I use the same input, and the algorithm is deterministic, thus the instructions should be the same. Then why the CPU time is different for different runs?

Comment: CPU cache misses. Variable CPU clock frequency (e.g. Intel SpeedStep and TurboBoost). If you're running under a hypervisor then that can affect things too. These are all factors that adjust CPU time of a process outside of IO waits.

Comment: I would imagine other processes affect the overall cache state so the CPU may not have the same cached resources between two separate runs.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things going on in the background that can effect the CPU timing, unless you are running on a micro-controller with no operating system.

Comment: Can you state what the Operating System is?  There will be lots of things the OS is doing in the background.

Comment: Also, the system you are running on is a big factor, for example if its Windows based, then the timing is not very accurate at all, due to the resolution of the system clock.